# ShareX link without the .png?

Tags: php, image, .htaccess, png

i'm not too experienced here so i'm not sure if it would be done with .htaccess or in the upload.php i have, but I was wondering how i can effectively remove the .png from the sharex link? So instead of something like `mydomain.com/abcdefg.png` it would be `mydomain.com/abcdefg` but link to the .png link, so that way it can embed on discord? I've already tried uploading it without the .png (so the file on the domain is just `abcdefg`) but it seems it won't embed on discord this way. Thanks!

Comment: Do you have a empty htaccess?

Comment: the only thing in my htaccess is for password locking the php file, so other than that, no

Comment: You should try something by yourself :-) you can do this with htaccess file

Comment: honestly i have no clue how, i've never properly done htaccess stuff but thank you for telling me where it should be at least, i'll give it a go :)

Comment: And, did you suceed?

Comment: Yes, i succeeded. Thanks for letting me know where to look :D